# PHP: merge two arrays from while loop + sorting

Tags: php, arrays, merge, while-loop

In Wordpress, every WP_query returns with posts. (in current situation I have 2 posts)
Every post contains some array. As a result I get two arrays and I need to merge them so I could Sort them later. 
So currently if I print:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($products_selected);
echo "</pre>";
```

I get This:

```
Array
(

    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => http://www.page1.com
            [1] => Product 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => http://www.page2.com
            [1] => Product 2

        )
)
```

Array 2:

```
Array
(

    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => http://www.page3.com
            [1] => Product 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => http://www.page4.com
            [1] => Product 4

        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => http://www.page5.com
            [1] => Product 5

        )

)
```

How do I merge them so I could sort by Product names ( [1] )

Example:

```
Array
(

    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => http://www.page1.com
            [1] => Product 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => http://www.page2.com
            [1] => Product 2

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => http://www.page3.com
            [1] => Product 3
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => http://www.page4.com
            [1] => Product 4

        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => http://www.page5.com
            [1] => Product 5

        )

)
```

Comment: I'd use `array_merge` and `usort`

Comment: [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-merge.php) and [usort](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.usort.php). though if you add some of your code maybe we can merge your two queries into one ...

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this exact result using the `array_merge_recursive($ array1, $ array2)`